Power BI Report Builder Multi Value Picklist returning blank
I have a report using DAX to pull from a PBI semantic dataset. When entering one criteria in the report parameter, it returns the result normally. However, when entering more than one value for the parameter (such as copy/paste a short list) it doesn't return any values.
DAX references the parameter like below:
filter('Table','Table'[Field] in {@parameter})
The parameter is set up within the dataset and 'allow multiple values' is selected in parameter advanced settings. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!
